# SELECT FROM not working, unknown column in order clause

Tags: sql

This was working yesterday, however today its not and im really unsure as to why

```
CREATE TABLE Performance 
(
    PerfDate DATE, 
    PerfTime TIME, 
    Title CHAR(10)
);

SELECT * 
FROM Performance 
WHERE Title = 'Cats' 
ORDER BY PerfTime; 

INSERT INTO Performance 
VALUES ('2017-11-01', '19:00:00', 'Cats'),
       ('2017-11-02', '19:00:00', 'Cats'),
       ('2017-11-03', '19:00:00', 'Cats'),
       ('2017-11-03', '13:00:00', 'Cats'),
       ('2017-11-04', '19:00:00', 'Fame'),
       ('2017-11-05', '13:00:00', 'Fame'),
       ('2017-11-05', '19:00:00', 'Tosca'),
       ('2017-11-06', '13:00:00', 'Tosca'), 
       ('2017-11-06', '19:00:00', 'Tosca');
```

I get an error that there's an unknown column in order clause, however I don't see how? Any help will be pleasure for me

Comment: If you have an issue with your `SELECT` statement, are you sure that we need to see several `INSERT INTO`'s following that?

Comment: Running this on an SQLFiddle I have rows returned as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/18827d/1

Comment: @BobKaufman, the column named PerfTime has data type time.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please remember to add the right tag to your question to indicate this. :)

Comment: Works just fine with the `time` data type: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d399e13f7dd8e06594c4bca3a4397387 but why aren't you using a single column that stores date and time (typically you would use a `timestamp` type for that)

Comment: The issue I see with the code is that you are running the SELECT prior to inserting any data so , if anything you should be getting an empty data set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on an MSSQL Server? Switch the database. That has been my problem in this case.

```sql
USE databasename
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from other's comments.  The only other thing I can think of is... You already HAVE a table by the name given.  It COULD have different column names than what you are presenting here because you are not pre-deleting a previous version.  If so, the table structure you are creating WOULD have thrown an error about the table already existing and should have been a direct indicator.